# Writing XML using java results in HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR

Tags: java, xml

can't seem to trace why i get an `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.`

Here is my snippet which of the actual writing

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement;
Element childElement;

/* iterate through list */
Iterator<Map<String,String>> mapItrList = mapList.iterator();
Map<String, String> tempMap;
String[] tempKeySet;

while(mapItrList.hasNext())
{
    tempMap = mapItrList.next();

    /* process each data */

    rootElement = doc.createElement(key);
    rootElement.setAttribute("id", tempMap.get(key));
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);


    tempKeySet = tempMap.keySet().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(",");

    for(int temp = 0; temp < tempKeySet.length; temp++)
    {   
        if(!tempKeySet[temp].equals(key))
        {
            childElement = doc.createElement("col");
            childElement.setAttribute("id", tempKeySet[temp].toString());
            childElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(tempMap.get(tempKeySet[temp])));
            rootElement.appendChild(childElement);
        }
        else
        {
            /* do nothing */
        }

    }

}


// write the content into xml file
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
//StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("file.xml"));
StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(System.out);

transformer.transform(source, result);

System.out.println("File saved!");
```

expected XML result

```
<Outer id="asdf">
    <col id="asdf">
        asdf
    </col>
    <col id="asdf3">
        asdf
    </col>
    ...
</Outer>
<Outer id="asdf">
    <col id="asdf">
        asdf
    </col>
    <col id="asdf3">
        asdf
    </col>
    ...
</Outer>
<Outer id="asdf">
    <col id="asdf">
        asdf
    </col>
    <col id="asdf3">
        asdf
    </col>
    ...
</Outer>
...
```

Key notes:

tempMap has this kind of strucutre

```
{
 Status1=status1, 
 Status2=status2, 
 Type=myType, 
 Status3=status3,
 Status4=status4
}
```

key refer to the `<Outer>` on XML

col refer to the inner loop

Just so you know why there is a `while`, that because im iterating through a list of Map so its expected to have many 
and inside Map there is also a number of inputs so in first iteration of while loop expected xml will be as below

```
<Outer id="asdf">
    <col id="asdf">
        asdf
    </col>
    <col id="asdf3">
        asdf
    </col>
    ...
</Outer>
```

But there seems to be an error that im having trouble tracing..

**============================UPDATE============================**

For the benefit of the people who have the same issue, as pointed by `kdgregory`
you have to specify one base element. that solved my case

Comment: A hint only, because this is basic debugging: how many root elements can be in an XML document?

Comment: 1, do i have to delcare 1 root before everything else? becuase i treat <outer> at my root.. so that my XML should look like that above :)

Comment: Do you create `<Outer>` anywhere? Also, I'm sure that the stack trace in the expression will show you *exactly* which line has the bug.

Comment: yes, i added a base element to contains all my outer and it produced a null pointer exception pointing to this line transformer.transform(source, result); btw i checked transformer, source, result.. its not null.. i read the api for transformer, it throws an exception if If an unrecoverable error occurs during the course of the transformation. what does that mean?

Comment: scratch previous comment.. was a access mistake that doesn't pertain to any of those that i stated :)